# Select two columns and take their count

Tags: php, mysql

I making one table, and i want to make table ordered by desc,

Example: Take Bank_Account + HandMoney = SUM, and write the sum of that by the Desc

I alredy maked Table by only "HandMoney" and it works good, but i realy dont know how to make sum of two columns

Code what i have now:

```
        $query = $connection -> prepare("SELECT `p_name`, `HandMoney` FROM `users` ORDER BY `HandMoney` DESC LIMIT 15"); 

        if($query -> execute()) 
        { 
            if($query -> rowCount()) 
            { 
                $count = 0; 

                ?> 
                <thead>
                <table class="table-fill2"> 
                <tbody class="table-hover">
                    <tr> 
                        <th class="text-left"> 
                            Postion
                        </th> 

                        <th class="text-left"> 
                            Player Name
                        </th> 

                        <th class="text-left"> 
                            Money
                        </th> 
                    </tr> 
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="table-hover">
                    <?php 

                    while($query_result = $query -> fetch()) 
                    { 
                        ?> 

                        <tr> 
                            <td style = "text-left"> 
                                <?php 

                                echo ++ $count; 

                                ?> 
                            </td> 

                            <td style = "text-left"> 
                                <?php 

                                echo $query_result['p_name']; 

                                ?> 
                            </td> 

                            <td style = "text-left"> 
                                <?php 

                                echo number_format($query_result['HandMoney']); 

                                ?> 
                            </td> 
                        </tr> 

                        <?php 
                    } 

                    ?> 
                </tbody>
                </table> 

                <?php 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                echo 'No players were found.'; 
            } 
        } 

        ?>
```

So i want take two columns (HandMoney + BankMoney = SUM) and order player by that sums

Comment: The tags serve the purpose of identifying what type of question it is, so that's not necessary to repeat in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you want to have that:

```
SELECT `p_name`, SUM(Bank_Account + HandMoney) as BandH
FROM `users` 
GROUP BY p_name
ORDER BY BandH DESC
```

Comment: Yeah but what with

echo number_format($query_result['HandMoney']);

It will be to 
echo number_format($query_result['HandMoney + Bank_Account']); 
Or something else

Comment: I want to make Top 15 players ordered by sum bank_account + handmoney

Comment: Fixed, Thank you!